# Maven jod LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException on jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, hudson

I am new to jenkins.When I try to build a maven project, I meet an exception.

```
     [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal
 in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-
version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, 
process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-
test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-
compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, 
integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-
clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
```

How can I deal with it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what happened is that when you setup the Maven build step, you wrote `mvn somegoal`

The maven build step already implies the `mvn` command. So, in the goals section only write the goal. Don't explicitly write the `mvn` command.

Answer (score 1):

Remove mvn and provide the goals only. Example *clean install package*

Answer (score 0):

**Error**:  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.**LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException** 
 For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/**LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException**

**Solution** : Unknown lifecycle phase or wrong goal **example**:First I am using "clean package tea-container-test:tomcat-test -P "XXX" -e" as goal , then I changed a goal as "test -P XXX" , then It works perfectly,so **Please check , your goal is right or wrong**.
"Creates a new exception to indicate that the specified lifecycle phase is not defined by any known lifecycle".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was like this:

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".1". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a 
goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>
[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. 
Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, 
process-sources, generate-resources, 
process-resources, compile, process-classes, 
generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, 
process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, 
pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, 
verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site,
 site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
```

The reason I found for this is I wrote `-Dversion=1.1` and not `-Dversion="1.1"`.
This is why it was showing an error.
I was trying to execute the following command in the .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
script:
    - 'mvn -X -e org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install-file -Dfile="C:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\BAMAEMCW\0\hridoy\maven-project-with-ci-cd\lib\json-simple-1.1.jar" -DgroupId=json-simple -DartifactId=json-simple -Dversion="1.1" -Dpackaging=jar'
```

Now, it executes without any error. I think in your case, check if any typos occurred!

Answer (score 0):

Unknown lifecycle phase `perform-whitesource-scan` getting this in configuration giving:

```
clean  deploy perform-whitesource-scan -Dwhitesource.scan.project.version=$POM_VERSION -Dws_ver=$POM_VERSION -P Sydney
```